# Why are animated gif in typo3 not shown

Tags: typo3, gif, typoscript

I have in my Typo3 Content text and image. And i would like to insert a animated gif. I first made it normal, than i recognized that the gif changed to .png files.

After a few test I found the parameter (FE `png_to_gif`), in the Install Tool.

But when I choose this. The gif files has the path fileadmin/processed but there are no gif files in this directory.

Can anybody help me that i can display my animated gifs ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the image you are processing is resized or modified by ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick, all frames of an animation will be lost. Use the orginal size in the frontend to avoid this.

Comment: And how ? I made in the Image Tab under View quality: none(all Options are ignored). With this option a have the original size in teh Frontend.

Comment: Very late, but anyway: original size = set the size of the uploaded gif to the size displayed in the frontend. If the gif is 200x200 pixel on the website, change it with a image editor to exactly this size (200x200) and then upload this to TYPO3. TYPO3 will not touch this file and show the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try select "None (ignores all other options)" under Apperance->Quality and Type

gl

Answer (score 0):

Like Merec answered: the animation will be lost trough processing ...
an option is to intervene on the rendering of the fluid-template: in your own extension you overwrite the original fluid-template and find the image-viewhelper the ouputs the image:

This processes the image also when no width or height are given

```
<f:image image="{imageObject}" />
```

This without size will not (or use the variable directly)

```
<f:image src="{imageObject.0.originalResource.publicUrl}" />
```

*(note that an imageobject is often an array, to find that out* `<f:debug>{_imageObject}</f:debug>` or  `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>`)